# Adding delay to aurioTouch sample program

Tags: objective-c, delay, core-audio

I am very new to Core Audio, and am trying to understand and modify Apple's aurioTouch sample code in order to delay the output by about 70ms. Does anyone have advice on how I can go about adding that delay?